# Why does del (x) with parentheses around the variable name work?

Tags: python

Why does this piece of code work the way it does?

```
x = 3
print(dir())   #output indicates that x is defined in the global scope
del (x)
print(dir())   #output indicates that x is not defined in the global scope
```

My understanding is that `del` is a keyword in Python, and what follows `del` should be a name. `(name)` is not a name. Why does the example seem to show that `del (name)` works the same as `del name`?

Comment: What follows `del` is not always a name; consider `del arr[n]` or `del obj.attr`.

Comment: You can put parentheses around any expression, and the value is the same as the expression. E.g. `foo = x` or `foo = (x)` are the same thing.

Comment: `del(name)` is interpreted as `del (name)`, and the parentheses are ignored. It's like doing `print('name')` in Python2.7, it is _interpreted_ as `print ('name')`.

Comment: You can `del` (almost?) anything you can assign to. You can assign to `(a, b)`, so you can `del (a, b)`. Similarly, you can assign to `(a)` (though it's probably a bad idea), so you can `del (a)` (though it's probably a bad idea). You can even assign `[] = any_empty_iterable` as a weird special case, so you can `del []` (which has no effect).

Comment: @user2357112 You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definition of the [`del` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) is:

```
del_stmt ::=  "del" target_list
```

and from the definition of [`target_list`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

```
target_list ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
target      ::=  identifier
                 | "(" target_list ")"
                 | "[" [target_list] "]"
                 | ...
```

you can see that parentheses around the list of targets are allowed.

For example, if you define `x,y = 1,2`, all of these are allowed and have the same effect:

```
del x,y
del (x,y)
del (x),[y]
del [x,(y)]
del ([x], (y))
```

Answer (score 0):

**[del](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) statement** with or without **parentheses** as shown below are the same:

---

```py
del (x)
```

```py
del x
```

---

And, **other statements** such as [**if**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement), [**while**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement), [**for**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) and [**assert**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) with or without **parentheses** as shown below are also the same:

---

```py
if (x == "Hello"):
```

```py
if x == "Hello":
```

---

```py
while (x == 3):
```

```py
while x == 3:
```

---

```py
for (x) in (fruits):
```

```py
for x in fruits:
```

---

```py
assert (x == 3)
```

```py
assert x == 3
```

---

In addition, basically, most example python code which I've seen so far doesn't use **parentheses** for `del`, `if`, `while`, `for` and `assert` statements so I prefer not using **parentheses** for them.